Sharing to GitHub from PyCharm is ignoring my code files
I am new to Python and to PyCharm, and have been trying to set up GitHub. I have been trying to share my first Python project (a stripped down version of Pokemon battling) to GitHub, and the project shared, but when I look on GitHub, it has the .ideas folder, but not .venv or any of the files it contains. I've discovered that in the Git menu these all show up as 'ignored files'. In the Youtube tutorials I've seen this didn't happen, and the code files were uploaded as expected. This happened automatically and the .gitignore file is empty. I want to know how to upload my code to GitHub.
Perhaps this is a common problem, but I have no idea what keywords I would need to search to find a solution.

Here is the empty .gitignore file:

Upon following Sharim's advice the file generated looked like this (the project used openpyxl):

None of my script files are listed, just the external directory; I presume this isn't what was meant to happen.


Can you show your gitignore file, and can you show the commits you did to gitignore file

and ", but not .venv or any of the files it contains" -  Why you want to upload this folder? It is not recommended to upload it to github

@Sharim09 I am completely new, so I didn't know that. I want to upload the code files contained in the scripts folder inside the .venv folder, though.

Why you want to upload it? Can you tell me please

There is a better way is just list all of the required module in a text file and upload that to github

@Sharim09 It might be that I have misunderstood how GitHub works, and that's what the tutorial was doing. Is this a different approach than sharing a project to GitHub using the inbuilt option?

Uploading your venv folder is not a recommended approach, as it can have a large size and some useless files that are not need.
Instead you can just upload your list of all libraries you are using.(requirements.txt)
To generate it you can run this command
pip freeze > requirements.txt

Make sure to run it in the project folder (and make sure that terminal is using the same virtual environment).
After that you have to only add and commit this file to the github

Now if anyone wants to use your code he can directly download your repo, and run this command to download all the requirements
pip install -r requirements.txt



And please don't create your code files in venv folder.

Select and move these files in your main project folder, except pyvenv.cfg file

I tried that and have edited my question showing what happened

@ZoeAllen Can you show the screenshot where you run the coimmand, are you sure your terminal was using the virtual env

and can you remove the * from gitignore.

I have added the screenshot to my question.

I removed the * and ran the command again, and nothing seemed to change.

@ZoeAllen is there any external lirbary you are using/

I am using openpyxl.

@ZoeAllen then so what is the problem now?

I mean it is now mentioned in your requirements file, just push this file to github and then no need to push the venv folder.

@ZoeAllen I have mentioned more steps in the answer, just mention the last command in your readme file, so that user can download all the lirabries

I don't understand how this would solve my problem. GitHub is still only seeing the .ideas folder- the script files don't show up at all, even as names in a list- so how could anyone download my code?

@ZoeAllen I have a question, is your written code is in venv folder? if Yes then why you put it in that folder]

You can see my file organisation in my second picture. The python files were created inside the .venv folder, which from what I've seen is the standard way of doing things.

@ZoeAllen Don't create files in venv folder, create it at the same level as venv, means on the parent folder.
